# Run remote java code locally

Tags: java, groovy

We have a client server application being used by more than 10000 users. Each one of these setups are deployed on-site on customer infrastructure(using tomcat server). These environment do get upgraded only on demand. In such an eco system is there a way to safely deploy remote code from centralized location programatically. 
We are doing something like following at the moment. The following code can be written and deployed on user-location which dynamically downloads and loads a class.

```
    ClassLoader cl = new ClassLoader() {};
    CachedCompiler cc = new CachedCompiler(null, null);
    //this javaCode comes as a string from a URL(remote location)
    Class aClass = cc.loadFromJava(cl, className, javaCode);                  
    Object instance = aClass.newInstance();
    Method method = instance.getClass().getMethod("execute");
    method.invoke(instance);
```

Given the nature of reflection we don't feel this may be a great way of running remote code/script in Java env. And also, this is not RMI or EJB because the hosted code is executed locally, essentially it can be broken down to following steps

1. Write code remotely
2. Download code locally
3. Execute code locally(in tomcat container)

It would be great to know if a technology already exists.

We have already seen something on the following line but not sure if have any apparent advantages over the code demonstrated above

```
def engine = new GroovyScriptEngine([tmpDir.toURI().toURL()] as URL[])
```

Comment: How about JNLP? Applet?

Comment: They are more of a client side technologies. I want to run it under tomcat container

Comment: Some mechanism that can be triggered to run remote code on a client's system sounds like a security nightmare...

Comment: @tim_yates definitely true, reminds me of spring security issue http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078687/scripting-jvm-languages/spring-framework-flaw-allows-remote-code-execution-by-attackers.html But this is something valid may be wrapped around encryption or security.